# How to use django inlines with a composite key?

Tags: python, django

and thank you for your help.

I'm using inlines in django to display a model in another admin model, it seems like it demmands a primary key, i get this error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/accounts/estadosm/18/change/
(1054, "Unknown column 'flora2estado.id' in 'field list'")
```

But!, the model actually have a composite key, like so:

```
class Flora2Estado(models.Model):

    estado = models.ForeignKey(EstadosM, models.DO_NOTHING)
    especie = models.ForeignKey('Listaflor', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'flora2estado'
        unique_together = (('estado', 'especie'),)
```

How can i fix this, to tell django admin fields to use the composite key?!

django.admin:

```
class flora2EstadosInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Flora2Estado
    fields = ['estado','especie'] 
    extra = 1

    def get_extra (self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        """Dynamically sets the number of extra forms. 0 if the related object
        already exists or the extra configuration otherwise."""
        if obj:
            # Don't add any extra forms if the related object already exists.
            return 0
        return self.extra
class EstadosAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [flora2EstadosInline]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get composite key works in Django

1. Drop composite key constrain and add single primary key column - https://info.crunchydata.com/blog/composite-primary-keys-postgresql-and-django
2. Use CompositeKey virtual field. I made the implementation, that represents a composite key as a single json value, that makes it works with django admin and inlines - https://viewflow.medium.com/the-django-compositeforeignkey-field-get-access-to-a-legacy-database-without-altering-db-tables-74abc9868026